# putting userid (or username) in url as querystring in Desire2Learn

Tags: url, query-string, desire2learn

I need to put a link in D2L to an external website. When the user click the link, his username should be included in the url, something like: www.abc.com/index.aspx?username=user1

Is there any parameter that can allow me do that easily? Like: index.aspx?username=**{userid}**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the user name of the currently-logged-in user is one of the *replacement strings* that you can use [in links placed in the LMS' UI](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/uiplugins.html#simple-urls). However, replacement strings do not get processed in all the places you could put a link in the LMS: for example, if you write a link into a discussion thread post or the like, I'm not sure that a replacement string used there would get expanded.

If you search on the web for "Desire2Learn replacement strings", you'll find a variety of pages hosted by various educational institutions that document a list of replacement strings that might work for you (in fact, `{UserName}` seems to be the one you want).

You should be aware thought that when you use a replacement string in an outbound URL that sends the information in the clear through the network: you may want to do this with caution, for privacy/security reasons.